# How do we know which element is minimum in loop kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Hey I have list in kotlin. I am iterating over it. I want to store  true/false as flag index which one is minimum value in whole list. I tried some code, but it's not working.

```
fun main() {
    val list = mutableListOf(4.83, 4.39, 3.58, 3.50, 3.46)
    val minValue = mutableListOf<BestMinimumValue>()
    var previousValue = 0.0

    list.forEach {
        minValue.add(BestMinimumValue(compareValue = previousValue > it))
        previousValue = it
    }
    minValue.forEach {
        println(it)
    }
}

data class BestMinimumValue(
    val compareValue: Boolean
)
```

**Actual Output**

```
BestMinimumValue(compareValue=false)
BestMinimumValue(compareValue=true)
BestMinimumValue(compareValue=true)
BestMinimumValue(compareValue=true)
BestMinimumValue(compareValue=true)
```

I'll explain what I need. In my list **3.46** is minimum value so on that place I need the flag as **true** and other one will be **false**.

**Expected Output**

```
BestMinimumValue(compareValue=false)
BestMinimumValue(compareValue=false)
BestMinimumValue(compareValue=false)
BestMinimumValue(compareValue=false)
BestMinimumValue(compareValue=true)
```

Comment: You can't really do it while iterating, because while you're at e.g. 2nd item, you don't know if it is the minimum or if there will be smaller item in next iterations. Anyway, do you really need such data structure? It looks pretty weird, if you ask me. Wouldn't it be enough to just use `list.minOrNull()`?

Comment: Yeah @broot I need this kind of structure. Do you have any other suggestions ? `minValue` is using my adapter so that's why i Stucked in this situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to create the resulting list while iterating, because we can't know if the current item is the smallest one or not. We have to iterate at least twice: first searching for the minimum value and then creating a resulting list.

One solution is to find the minimum and then compare items to it:

```kotlin
val min = list.minOrNull()!!
val minValue = list.map { BestMinimumValue(it == min) }
```

Note if there are multiple same minimum values, then all of them will be marked as `true`.

If this is not expected behavior or if we like to avoid comparing items twice, then we can find the index of the minimum value and just construct the resulting list with it:

```kotlin
val minIndex = list.withIndex().minByOrNull { it.value }!!.index
val minValue = List(list.size) { BestMinimumValue(it == minIndex) }
```